# RestEasy with Spring renders no answer

Tags: spring, resteasy

I can see that the FilterDispatcher is called (by debugger), but it doesn't seem to find the service to call. I've got trouble grasping how RestEasy actually maps between resources defined in Spring and RestEasy.

Main story: Getting http://my.local.no:8087/rest/typeaheads/h only renders 404

*web.xml*:

```
...
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>restFilterDispatcher</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>restFilterDispatcher</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
```

resteasy resource is set up by bean:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = TypeaheadsRestService.class)
public class SpringConfig {
}
```

*TypeaheadsRestService.java*:

```
@Resource
@Path("/typeaheads")
public class TypeaheadsRestService {
    @GET
    @Path("/{search}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<NameUrl> get(@PathParam("search") String search) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the client code also

Comment: The request should have a header `Accepts: application/json`

Comment: Tried the header; but it didn't change anything.

Comment: About the client code: I use WizTools.org RESTClient. Nice simple tool actually.

Comment: Another problem might be the url, you have the pattern `/rest/*` mapped to `restFilterDispatcher`, but your url `/typeaheads/{search}` does not match the filter

Comment: Path is relative to the mapping prefix. Tried just to be sure, but to no avail.

Comment: web is the servlet mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RestEasy *SpringContextLoaderListener* seem to be the missing part. I created a stripped down problem from RestEasy example and used it. For my somewhat more complex application however it would not work. That is probably because it overrides the deprecated *createContextLoader*-method. In Spring 3 *ContextLoaderListener* is an instance of *ContextLoader*. So I reimplemented it like this:

```
public class MyContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener {
    private SpringContextLoaderSupport springContextLoaderSupport = new SpringContextLoaderSupport();
    @Override
    protected void customizeContext(ServletContext servletContext, ConfigurableWebApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        super.customizeContext(servletContext, applicationContext);
        this.springContextLoaderSupport.customizeContext(servletContext, applicationContext);
    }
}
```

I originally tried to do the *customizeContext(...)* in a bean initialisation. That worked in RestEasy 2.2.1.GA, but not in 2.3.4.FINAL.